# How to call a function on multiple images inside canvas html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to place multiple images on one canvas and move them upwards, as soon as they reach the top respawn at the bottom again.

This is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');



function image(src) {
    var x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - 94);
    var y = 400;
    var speed = (- Math.random() * (+5 - +1) +1);

    //creating the image object
    var image = new Image(); 
    window.onload = function() {
        //setting the source of the image to the passed in src param
        image.src = src; 

        this.update = function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
            context.beginPath();
            context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, 94,229);
            context.fill();
            context.closePath();
        
            if(this.y  <= (-canvas.height)-30) {
                this.y = 400;
                this.x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - 100);
                console.log("respawned" + x);
            }
            this.y += speed;
    }}}

    window.onload = function(){
        createImages();
    }

    function createImages(){
        var image1 = new image("../Website/Assets/sadballoon.png");
        var image2 = new image("../Website/Assets/red.jpg");
        //var images = [image1,image2];
    
        setInterval(
            function() {
                image1.update();
                image2.update();
                console.log("calling update");  
            },10);
    }
```

The error i am getting is Uncaught TypeError: image1.update is not a function
   which i understand that i am making an Image object and not the function image() object. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You could have the `Image` object be a property of your `image` class.

```
window.onload = function() {
    function image(src) {
        var x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - 94);
        var y = 400;
        var speed = (- Math.random() * (+5 - +1) +1);

        var image = new Image(); //Creating the image property of our Image class to store an HTML Image object
        image.src = src; //assigning the appropriate src to our image

        this.update = function() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
            context.beginPath();
            context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, 94,229);
            context.fill();
            context.closePath();

            if(this.y  <= (-canvas.height)-30) {
                this.y = 400;
                this.x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - 100);
                console.log("respawned" + x);
            }
            this.y += speed;
        }
    }

    function createImages(){
        var image1 = new image("../Website/Assets/sadballoon.png");
        var image2 = new image("../Website/Assets/red.jpg");
        var images = [image1,image2];

        setInterval(
        function() {
            image1.update();
            image2.update();
        },10);
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    createImages();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! good idea to create Image object inside my image class, but i am still getting the error of image1.update() is not a function.

Comment: It may be because you've forgotten to declare the image1 and image2 variables with the `var` keyword, I've updated my code to fix.

Comment: I added the var keyword earlier. It wasn't what was causing the problem. There is something not quite right with my code still.

Comment: I copied my code and ran it and it seems to work fine. The issue could also be to do with the fact you are globally declaring a variable `image` at the start of your code (line 3). Try removing or renaming this or rename the `image` function/class.

Comment: You say you tested the code and it works, can you than explain what are `innerWidth, innerHeight` and where you defined them? ;)

Comment: innerWidth and innerHeigth : "Definition and Usage
The innerWidth property returns the width of a window's content area.

Those variables return the width and height of the canvas so i can place the image inside of it
The innerHeight property returns the height of a window's content area."

Comment: I removed the image variable on line 3. The issue appears when i call the createImages() function to actually create the images and place them on the screen. Thats when the image1.update()  error apears.

Comment: Copy and paste my code, it's definitely working for me. You seem to be using Window.onload incorrectly, this is generally only used once as a wrapper function for all the code you want to be run. You can get rid of it completely.

Comment: Are you getting images to appear though? Cause your code doesnt call the createImages function? Sorry for all these questions mate.

Comment: Call the createImages function seperately at the end. I'll add that to my code. Don't worry about all the questions! That's what this website is for.